# Is the HTTP content-range header compatible with chunked transfer encoding?

Tags: http, networking

As above, is byte serving chunked transfer possible in the HTTP standard?

Answer (score 2):

From RFC2616, Transfer-Encoding is a property of the message, not the entity. Content-Range is an entity-header. So in principle they can be used together, unless there exists some corner case where the two conflict.

Here is how it is supposed to happen: use asterisk "*" as the instance-length. Omit the content-length header and send Transfer-Encoding: chunked.

Comment: You mean *omit* the Content-length header.

Comment: From a server point of view, it should *omit* Content-Length header when sending "Transfer-Encoding: chunked". From a client point of view it can only ignore the Content-Length header in case it is received with a Transfer-Encoding: chunked.